# Auto login in Power BI with REST API with cron task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, powerbi, office365-restapi

I want auto login in Azure portal for access_token so that I can send data to Power BI dataset . From cron task in Rails App currently I am using

```
OAuth2::Client
```

and

`OAuth2::AccessToken` for generating token.

I add `username`, `password` , `grant_type => 'password'` and `scope => 'openid`' to `OAuth2::Client` but it is not working something is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this. Now I am using `rest_client` instead of `Oauth2`

```
request =  RestClient.post( url,
      {
        :grant_type => 'password', 
          :scope => 'openid',
          :resource => 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api',
          :client_id => 'CLIENT_ID',
          :client_secret => 'CLIENT_SECRET',
          :username => 'USERNAME',
          :password => 'PASSWORD'

      })
```